# Problems when deploying MERN stack app in Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, heroku, mern

What is the solution to this problem? I'm getting this error while trying to deploy a MERN stack in Heroku. What I did is: I configured MONGO_URI, PORT, etc. Pushed all working code in Github still getting this error. What should I do to be able to deploy this app successfully? I tried deploying the application by reading Heroku documentation and watching youtube tutorial.

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  14.16.1
       engines.npm (package.json):   6.14.12
       
       Resolving node version 14.16.1...
       Downloading and installing node 14.16.1...
       npm 6.14.12 already installed with node
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       
       > nodemon@2.0.7 postinstall /tmp/build_5044977d/node_modules/nodemon
       > node bin/postinstall || exit 0
       
       Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
        > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate
       
       
       > bcrypt@5.0.1 install /tmp/build_5044977d/node_modules/bcrypt
       > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
       
       [bcrypt] Success: "/tmp/build_5044977d/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node" is installed via remote
       added 365 packages in 9.194s
       
-----> Build
       Running heroku-postbuild
       
       > car-app@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_5044977d
       > NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix frontend && npm run build --prefix frontend
       
       up to date in 0.234s
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /tmp/build_5044977d/frontend/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/build_5044977d/frontend/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.GU88T/_logs/2021-07-02T10_17_10_423Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 254
npm ERR! car-app@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix frontend && npm run build --prefix frontend`
npm ERR! Exit status 254
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the car-app@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.GU88T/_logs/2021-07-02T10_17_10_446Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is heroku postbuild issue then first run

```js
npm run build
```

in your local system inside client folder(frontend application), it will throw an error if some dependency is missing inside your react app,

if build command is successful only then delete node_modules and package-lock.json file and then run

```js
npm install
```